# Is it possible to see a history of interaction with tables in a Redshift schema?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Ultimately, I would like to obtain a list of tables in a particular schema that haven't been queried in the last two weeks (say).

I [know](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_system-tables.html) that there are many system tables that track various things about how the Redshift cluster is functioning, but I have yet to find one that I could use to obtain the above.

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Is audit logging enabled on your cluster?

Comment: @RahulGupta Yes, it is.

Comment: Logs must have been stored on S3 configured while enabling audit logging. You can import user activity and/or user log files into redshift through copy command and run query against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at our "Unscanned Tables" query: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminScripts/unscanned_table_summary.sql

Comment: Nice!  This is very useful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled audit logging for the cluster, activity data stored inside a S3 bucket which you configured while enabling logging.

According to [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/db-auditing.html), audit log bucket structure is as follows.

> AWSLogs/AccountID/ServiceName/Region/Year/Month/Day/AccountID_ServiceName_Region_ClusterName_LogType_Timestamp.gz
>
> For example: AWSLogs/123456789012/redshift/us-east-1/2013/10/29/123456789012_redshift_us-east-1_mycluster_userlog_2013-10-29T18:01.gz